# Is it possible to write a conditional statement in the head markup of a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, community, conditional

I want to write a functional statement in the head markup of a VisualForce page. Is this possible? 
If it is possible, what is the right way to write it? I want a different href depending on the community the user is in. Im trying it like this but it is not working

```
<link type="image/png" rel="shortcut icon" href="{!IF($Network.Name=='partners', "/partners/resource/B2B_Favicon", "/customers/resource/B2B_Favicon")}" />
```

Comment: Add the exact error text you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it with this line:

```
href="{! IF( $Network.Name=='partners', '/partners/resource/B2B_Favicon' , '/customers/resource/B2B_Favicon') }"
```

i.e. by changing to single quotes.

Comment: If you have solved your problem and answered it, please don't forget to mark your answer as accepted

Comment: This is only possible after 2 days, I will do it as soon as it is possible.

Comment: @Ant - > check answer reminder =P